# Matlab: reshaping a matrix into a 1D array with overlapping elements added together

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Here is an example matrix:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5;6,7,8,9,10;11,12,13,14,15]'; % 1:5 in 1st column, 6:10 in 2nd etc
```

so I have:

```
x=
1 6  11
2 7  12
3 8  13
4 9  14
5 10 15
```

I want to overlap the upper half of elements of a given column (not including mid element) with the lower half of the previous column, adding the elements in the overlap. The first and last column will obviously be the exception (first column doesn't have a previous column, and nothing to add to last column)

in the simplistic example above, I have rewritten the line to show what numbers to overlap for clarity:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5;
         6,7,8,9,10;
               11,12,13,14,15]';
```

hence, I want the result to be:

```
y=[1;2;3;4+6;5+7;8;9+11;10+12;13;14;15];
```

Now, this is just a very simple example. The resulting code needs to scale well/run efficiently with big data. Likely size of the matrix will be something like 120000x600 and I think the resulting 1D array will be something like 37000000x1

Comment: So, is `x` now `120000x600` or `600x120000`? With the former I am getting an output length of `36060000`.

Answer (score 5):

### Answer to original question (add shifted *rows*):

This can be done as follows:

1. Generate an indexing vector (`ind`) such that entries of `x` to be summed have the same index. This can be done with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). The index can be computed once and reused for different `x` vectors (the index doesn't depend on `x`).
2. Use that indexing vector to do the sum with [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

Code:

```
n = ceil(size(x,2)/2);
ind = bsxfun(@plus, 1:size(x,2), (0:size(x,1)-1).'*n); %'// step 1. Valid for any x
y = accumarray(ind(:), x(:));                          % // step 2. Depends on x
```

### Answer to edited question (add shifted *columns*):

Transpose `x` and proceed as above:

```
x = x.';
n = ceil(size(x,2)/2);
ind = bsxfun(@plus, 1:size(x,2), (0:size(x,1)-1).'*n);for any x
y = accumarray(ind(:), x(:));
```

Comment: Thanks but I seem to get a different result (which might be my fault apologies).
x=[1,2,3,4,5;6,7,8,9,10;11,12,13,14,15]'; %input matrix
.

y=[1;2;3;10;12;8;20;22;13;14;15]; %result I want
.

y2= [1;6;13;7;15;8;17;9;19;10;15]; %is the result i got

Comment: So in the input matrix, the first column is 1:5, second column is 6:10, and third column is 11:15

And in this case, I am adding the top two elements in the second column to the bottom two elements in the first column, as well as adding the top two elements in the third column to the bottom two elements of 'then' second column

Comment: @user3120554 You've __changed__ the question adding a transpose in the data! So now you want to sum columns, not rows! Of course my answer doesn't work with your modified question. I answered the original question, and __then__ you edited it. Sorry but I've removed my upvote from your question. Anyway, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

The addititions can be calculated with one matrix matrix addition and after this you reorder your result.

The matrix matrix addition has the form

```
x = [1  2  3  4  5;
     6  7  8  9  10;
     11 12 13 14 15];

A = [4 5; 9 10] + [6 7; 11 12]
```

The first and the last rows and the middle column are unchanged.
This yields the following code:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5;6,7,8,9,10;11,12,13,14,15]';

x = x.';

n = ceil(size(x,2)/2);
m = floor(size(x,2)/2);

A = [x(1:(end-1),(m+1):n) x(2:end,1:m)+x(1:(end-1),(n+1):end)]';

y = [x(1,1:m) A(:)' x(end,(m+1):end)];
```

The result is `y = 1 2 3 10 12 8 20 22 13 14 15`

It needs 1.3 seconds for `x=rand(120000,600)`

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to make it clear that x should be transposed here as shown in the op now (1:5 are in the first column etc)

Comment: That's not a big difference. The additions are in both cases a matrix matrix addition of the upper right block and the lower left block. Than the first and last lines are added.

Comment: @user3120554, y cant u just add `x=x.'` before the code?

Answer (score 0):

This could be one approach -

```
%// Get size
[n,m] = size(x)

%// Indices of first overlapping elements and its length
first_overlap = ceil(n/2)+1:n
overlap_len = numel(first_overlap)

%// Store the last elements of overlapping length to be appended at final stage
rem_ele = x(end-numel(first_overlap)+1:end)

%// Indices of overlapping elements across all columns
idx = bsxfun(@plus,first_overlap(:),[0:m-2]*n)

%// Do summations of overlaps and store back tto the next group of overlaps
x(idx(:)+overlap_len) = x(idx(:)) + x(idx(:)+overlap_len)

%// Remove elements from the previous overlaps
x(end-overlap_len+1:end,:)=[]

%// Output array after appending rem_ele to column vector version of modified x
out = [x(:) ; rem_ele(:)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most scalable solution, but likely a readable and intuitive one:

```
% Split the matrix into three parts
left  = x(:,1:floor(end/2));
mid   = x(:,floor(end/2)+1:ceil(end/2));
right = x(:,ceil(end/2)+1:end);

% Extend the middle part by one, note that this works even if mid is empty
mid(end+1,:) = nan;

% Construct a new matrix by summing up left and right parts
X = [left(1,:); ...
     left(2:end,:) + right(1:end-1,:); ...
     right(end,:)];

% Add the midpoints back
X=[X, mid].';

% Reshape into vector and remove the possible extra mid point 
y = X(1:end-~isempty(mid));
```